# LTspice - RF LPF design insert loss shows -6 dB

Tags: rf, ltspice

I am trying to simulate an LPF in LTspice, but the insertion loss shows up as -6 dB while I expect the value to be close to 0.

Am I setting the simulation up wrong?

[image]

Comment: Insertion loss is defined as the difference between amplitude of a straight pass-through, and amplitude with the filter "inserted". Have you measured the reference amplitude here?

Answer (score 3):

The source impedance and load resistor form a resistive voltage divider, giving you half of the input voltage at the output. (That's -6dB.)

This is completely normal for a series-terminated AC voltage source, such as the one in your simulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the correct way to set it up to avoid -6 dB?

Comment: @Aryia I don’t know if there’s a “correct” way because nothing is wrong. But if the -6dB bothers you for some reason then change the AC amplitude from 1 to 2.

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you that worked!